# Looking for an app to control a tablet or smart device from a PC

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, remote-control

Everything I find when I search for this topic is how to control a PC from a tablet/smart device, but I'm looking to control my tablet/phone from a PC.

I've used TeamViewer in the past, but it is unreliable and requires participation on both sides.

I am looking for something that acts similarly to Chrome Remote Desktop in that **I can set it up on both sides, but don't need permission or assistance when remoting in.**

I have tablets at each of my companies locations nationwide and can't rely on someone being able to stand by while I remote in (see: TeamViewer).

Are there any apps that meet this criterion?

Comment: Looks like you've missed my corresponding app listings: [Control your Droid from your Computer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid) and [Manage your Android Device from your Computer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement). You'll probably want something from the latter (as the VNC servers from the former have quite shrunk down; several disappeared and what's left seems no longer maintained).